# Calculating Div and Mod using recursion

Tags: python, loops, recursion, html-helper, recursive-query

I am fairly new to Python trying my best to wrap my head around this however it's a lot harder than I thought. I am attempting to write recursive functions in python that calculate div and mod.
div takes two integers as input and keeps on subtracting the second from the first until the
first number becomes less than the second number. The function keeps a track of how many
times the second number is subtracted from the first and returns that number as the answer.
mod also takes two integers as input and keeps on subtracting the second from the first
until the first number becomes less than the second number. When the first number
becomes less than the second, the value of the first number is the answer.

```
def lastDigit(x):
 return mod(x,10)



def allButLast(x):
 return div(x,10)
```

Any help would be great thank you.

Comment: You haven't written anything for someone to help with.

Comment: Why do you need recursion for this? A simple loop would be much easier to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works as long as p>=0 and q>0.

```
def mod(p,q):
    if p<q:
        return p
    return mod(p-q,q)

def div(p,q):
    if p<q:
        return 0
    return 1+div(p-q,q)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, OI understand and I am so sorry, I should have given the code I actually tried.  Thank you, it works and I understand.

Comment: @CryptoDeity I'm not the one who gave you that feedback, so certainly no need to apologize to me. Anyway, if you're happy with this answer, please "accept" it by clicking the checkmark below the up/down vote arrows to the left of my post.